# I am working on Hostel Management System and i am confused about database

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design

I am working on Hostel Management System building on c# .Net and their are master section which have Hostel , building, wing , room , room type masters forms etc. In hostel form i am getting input as hostel name and saving in hostelm table and after in building form i am fetching hostel name from hostel table and getting input building name saving details but i am occurring error.

**Error**

> An error occurred: Cannot insert the value NULL into column
> 'HostelName, table 'Hostel Management System.dbo.BuildingM'; column
> does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The statement has been terminated.

**here database tables which i have created in database. please help me about solving error.**

The DDL for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE HostelM
(
   HostelID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   HostelName NVARCHAR(100)
      UNIQUE NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE BuildingM
(
   BuildingID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   HostelName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
      REFERENCES HostelM (HostelName),
   BuildingName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE WingM
(
   WingID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   BuildingID INT NOT NULL
      FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BuildingM (BuildingID),
   WingName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE FloorM
(
   FloorID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   WingID INT NOT NULL
      FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES WingM (WingID),
   FloorNumber INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE RoomTypeM
(
   RoomTypeID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   FloorID INT NOT NULL
      FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FloorM (FloorID),
   RoomTypeName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   RoomAssets NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE RoomM
(
   RoomID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   FloorID INT NOT NULL
      FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FloorM (FloorID),
   RoomTypeID INT NOT NULL
      FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RoomTypeM (RoomTypeID),
   RoomNumber INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AcademicYearM
(
   AcademicYearID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   YearName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
   EndDate DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CourseM
(
   CourseID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   CourseName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE FacultyM
(
   FacultyID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   FacultyName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I looks like your INSERT statement into the table BuildingM is missing the value of HostelName. Can you also provide your INSERT statement?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really too specific about this question that probably couldn't be answered by Googling the exception message:
**An error occurred: Cannot insert the value NULL into column**

Here's a link to an existing answer on StackOverFlow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391946/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-x-column-x-does-not-allow-nulls-inser

From that answer:
*The column is specified to be NOT NULL but has no default value. You are not inserting a value, so it gets the default. The default default is NULL, and that is not allowed.*

Maybe you want null values to be allowed into the Hostel Table? Then change the table to allow nulls:

```
CREATE TABLE HostelM
(
   HostelID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   HostelName NVARCHAR(100)
      UNIQUE NULL -- Change from NOT NULL to NULL
);
```